# Tuning Mac OS X 10.7 Lion international text-to-speech voices

Tags: macos, osx-lion, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Unlike English voices, international voices can't be tuned using embedded speech commands.

Are there any workarounds to make a word be pronounced with a different stress pattern?

I've tried tinkering with punctuation but nothing satisfies me fully.

Comment: Is this programming related? Maybe [apple.se]? If that's the case,  please don't cross-post, either flag for migration or delete-here/post-there.

Comment: It isn't strictly related to programming languages. However, it is within the scope of developing, so I guess here is better than there.

Comment: I researched this back in 10.7, but I couldn’t find a way. Hope that you will be more successful! The speech backend seems to be from Nuance, but their commands didn’t work for me.